# How to make a call via my application on Android?

Tags: android, voip, telephony

I have an Android application that can make calls via internet or " VoIP ".
So, I need the telephony API to put my application as a suggestion when a user dials-up a number !

any suggestions on how to do that ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register an intent filter in the manifest for your dialer activity:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: ok , I test your answer but it gives me no results ! to be specific I create test app with simple activity ! and I put DIAL into my Intent filter but when I dial a number nothing shows up ! Android still use the default ! no suggestions appear .... I'm developing for Android 2.1 if it help !